# Am I required to overload my insertion operator here?

Tags: c++

Am I automatically required to overload the insertion operator when trying to `cout` an object?

Here is my simple client file that I am using to practice overloading for my assignment:

```
int main()
{
  const fraction fr[] = {fraction(1,2), fraction(3,4), fraction(5,6)};


  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    cout << "fraction [" << i <<"] = " << fr[i] << endl;
  }

  system("pause");
}
```

And here is the relevant portion of my header file that works in place of `cout`:

```
void fraction::print() const
{
  cout << numer << " is the numerator " << denom << " is the denominator" << endl;
}
```

So when I delete the `cout` line and replace it with a call to my print function it works fine and it prints out each corresponding parameter's value for each fraction I have in my array. But if I try to use `cout` it freaks out and gives me a compiler error. Is this because I need to overload the insertion operator?

If someone can just explain my error using terminology I would rather learn through that method instead of just some random working bit of code. I really need to learn the material here so if you guys can just explain in words what the deal is, that would be awesome.

Comment: In the future, format your code with the `{}` button for best readability.

Comment: Is the title addressing someone named "Noob"?

Comment: No I just wanted to title my question with the warning that it was a noob question, not some crazy deep intensity

Comment: `<<` is the *insertion* operator: it *inserts* the value into a stream. `>>` is the *extraction* operator: it extracts a value from a stream.

Comment: @Casey: Actually they are shift operators.  But most C++ programmers seem to have forgotten that these operators weren't created for iostreams.

Comment: @BenVoigt You are correct to say that `<<` is a shift operator, but I don't think that it applies to this context. In the context of the question, Casey is right to call it the [insertion operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)

Comment: @MARS: It doesn't have the precedence which insertion ought to have, because it is neither more nor less than an overridden bitshift operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to overload the << operator. There is documentation here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: So any time I use an operand with an object I am required to overload that operand? That is what I am getting from this, I don't know why I didn't get that before.

Comment: @HunterGraves, think of it this way: "how is the compiler supposed to know which value(s) of my object to output if I don't tell it?"